# Java Executor never starts

Tags: java, executorservice, executor

I'm currently having an issue where I'm setting up an ExecutorService, but the call to newFixedthreadPool never completes.  I have a logger statement immediately after it that never executes.

Is there something about it that would be causing it to never complete?  This has never happened before with the same code, so I'm very confused.

```
ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.numStreams); 
logger.trace("Thread pool set up.");                                
for (int i = 1; i <= this.numStreams; i++)                          
{                                                                   
    logger.trace("Starting a new thread for stream {}", i);         
    Future f = ex.submit(new TestThread(c, c.getStreamIterator(i), this.config));
    logger.trace("New thread has been started.");                   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you log configuration still writes ``trace``?...

Comment: other **trace** log are coming??

Comment: Arg...dammit...yeah, I thought I had it configured to do so...thanks for setting me straight.